# 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: providers list cannot contain null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a Spring Boot application, a simple example to be able to load a web interface and create, retrieve, update and delete entities (for example students in a school), with some operations being restricted to certain users (therefore I'm using Spring Security). It was working fine, but after making a few changes suggested by Checkstyle and PMD, it no longer runs, instead throwing the following stack trace:

```
2020-08-08 18:19:48.608 ERROR 30203 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: providers list cannot contain null values
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: providers list cannot contain null values
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: providers list cannot contain null values
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.checkState(ProviderManager.java:149) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>(ProviderManager.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.performBuild(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:236) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.performBuild(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:50) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:118) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:269) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:202) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.config.SpringSecConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$76cdcc3a.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

The changes were things like making parameters and variables final where possible, which normally wouldn't cause this. The only classes of my own referenced in the stack trace are the main class and the Spring Security configuration class:

**SpringSecConfig.java**

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Spring Security configuration class.
 * @author Me
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class SpringSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { //NOPMD
  /**
   * The authentication provider.
   */
  private AuthenticationProvider provider; //NOPMD

  /**
   * Mutator for the authentication provider.
   * @param provider The authentication provider.
   */
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
  public void setProvider(final AuthenticationProvider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new BCrypt-based password encoder.
   * @return The password encoder.
   */
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a DaoAuthenticationProvider with BCrypt-based password encryption 
   * that uses the provided service.
   * @param service The service to load user data.
   * @return An AuthenticationProvider.
   */
  @Bean("daoAuthenticationProvider")
  public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(final UserDetailsService service) {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(service);
    return provider;
  }

  /**
   * Assigns an authentication provider to the Authentication Manager Builder.
   * @param authMB The Authentication Manager Builder.
   */
  @Autowired
  public void configureAuthManager(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authMB) {
    authMB.authenticationProvider(provider);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity //NOPMD
    .authorizeRequests()
    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources() //NOPMD
        .atCommonLocations())
    .permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**", "/people", "/person/show/*", "/console/*", "/h2-console/**")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and().logout()
        .permitAll();

    httpSecurity.csrf().disable(); //NOPMD
    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable(); //NOPMD
  }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Point of entry of the application.
 * @author Me
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication { //NOPMD

  /**
   * Main method.
   * @param args The arguments.
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

There is a related but unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329340/springsecurityfilterchain-threw-exceptionnested-exception-is-java-lang-illega?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C324.8060).

I understand that the list of providers checked in org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.checkState() contains a null value and that's what's causing the problem. But I can't figure out why it contains that null value. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your on AuthenticationProvider is not yet ready before configureAuthManager is called, try using  (not tested)

```
  @Autowired
  public void configureAuthManager(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authMB, @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider") AuthenticationProvider provider) {
    authMB.authenticationProvider(provider);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. Do note that the provider I'm assigning is a member of the class. I did try the following modification to your proposed code to no avail too:


`@Autowired
  public void configureAuthManager(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authMB, @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider") AuthenticationProvider provider) {
    setProvider(provider);
    authMB.authenticationProvider(this.provider);
  }`

Comment: What did work, however, was your suggestion plus autowiring the entity repository in a class I was using to bootstrap the application with mock data. So it seems your suggestion **did** work and I just had two errors to solve, but the one I initially reported took priority and I only saw the second one after solving the first, but mistook it as your solution not working. I stand corrected, and will accept your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In case of spring version 3.0 and spring security version 6.0 onwards, if your httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationProvider) is failing with similar error "**providers list cannot contain null values**" then it indicates that the authentication provider must not have been initialized before the SecurityFilterChain bean. Make sure your AuthenticationProvider bean gets initialized before SecurityFilterChain bean. This can be done by using @DependsOn("authenticationProviderBeanName") in your SecurityFilterChain bean.

Code will look something like this -

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(args...)
{...}

@Bean
**@DependsOn("authenticationProvider")**
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {...}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I resolve it with making my authenticationProvider as public final.
My code:

```
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);

    return  http.build();
}
```